# How to pretty print a 3D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, pretty-print

I have a three-dimensional int array and would like to pretty-print it in this format:

```
[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]
[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]
[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]

[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]
[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]
[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]

[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]
[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]
[n,n,n] [n,n,n] [n,n,n]
```

I tried using the code below but it didn't print it right because the second and third columns have to be appended to the same line as the first column:

```java
int[][][] hardestOne = {
    {{8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}},
    {{0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0}},
    {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 8, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0}}
};

public String toString() {
    String s = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < table[i][j].length; k++) {
                if (k == 2 || k == 5) {
                    s += table[i][j][k] + "\n";
                } else {
                    s += table[i][j][k] + "";
                }
            }
            s += "\n\n";
        }
        s += "\n";
    }

    return s;
}
```

**UPDATE:** I changed the example array to be more readable.

**UPDATE 2:** User @samurott gave a really good answer but there is this problem:

Consider these three lines which represent the first block in my array

```
{{8, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}, {0, 7, 0}},
{{0, 0, 0}, {6, 0, 0}, {0, 9, 0}},
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}
```

Looking at those lines above the printing should look like this

```
[8,0,0] [0,0,0] [0,0,0]
[0,0,3] [6,0,0] [0,0,0]
[0,7,0] [0,9,0] [2,0,0]
```

But when I print it using his code it looks like this

```
[8,0,0] [0,0,3] [0,7,0]
[0,0,0] [6,0,0] [0,9,0]
[0,0,0] [0,0,0] [2,0,0]
```

You see I could change all the positions of the array but it's gonna get more and more confusing later on.

**SOLUTION:** See the solution below made by user [@Alex R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7970787/alex-r)

Comment: @Reimeus I tried that but it prints all in one line, I want it in the format that I showed.

Comment: Things aren't that easy. What if one cell contains 582, and another one -2934? Meaning: before you even start printing, you will have to determine the *max* width for each column, and then you want to align your numbers accordingly.

Comment: probably something wrong with ```if (k == 2 || k == 5)``` shouldnt you be comparing with array ```lenght```?

Comment: @GhostCat that stuff is going to be done in a class which will validate everything, this method is actually the overriden toString() method.

Comment: Hint: when you want something laid out nicely and especially if you need data padded to a constant width then use [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).  This may help too: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-formatter

Comment: Your comment doesnt change anything about what I said. I saw that you return a string, but even in such strings you can insert spaces to ensure you get to the desired alignment. Without that, your output will not align correctly when your numbers have different width.

Comment: @GhostCat I should have explained what I'm trying to do, I'm doing a Sudoku solver to learn Backtracking, I know the numbers are not going to be anything else other than from 0 to 9 and this pretty-print is literally only for me to visualize the board better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here would be a reusable solution for 3x3 matrices. This only works if the array contains numbers from 0 to 9. Additional formatting is needed if you want to support other integers as well.

```
public final class TableFormatter {
private static final int[][][] TABLE = {
        {{8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}},
        {{0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0}},
        {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 8, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0}}
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TableFormatter formatter = new TableFormatter(TABLE);
    System.out.println(formatter.toString());
}

private final int[][][] array3d;

public TableFormatter(int[][][] array3d) {
    this.array3d = array3d;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int[][] array2d : array3d) {
        append2dArray(builder, array2d);
        builder.append('\n');
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

private void append2dArray(StringBuilder builder3d, int[][] array2d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            StringBuilder builder2d = new StringBuilder("[");
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                builder2d.append(array2d[j][(i * 3) + k]).append(',');
            }
            builder2d.deleteCharAt(builder2d.length() - 1).append("]\t");
            builder3d.append(builder2d);
        }
        builder3d.append('\n');
    }
}
}
```

**Output:**

```
[8,0,0] [0,0,0] [0,0,0] 
[0,0,3] [6,0,0] [0,0,0] 
[0,7,0] [0,9,0] [2,0,0] 

[0,5,0] [0,0,7] [0,0,0] 
[0,0,0] [0,4,5] [7,0,0] 
[0,0,0] [1,0,0] [0,3,0] 

[0,0,1] [0,0,0] [0,6,8] 
[0,0,8] [5,0,0] [0,1,0] 
[0,9,0] [0,0,0] [4,0,0]
```

If you want support for general matrices, you would have to pass the dimension as an argument to the constructor and update the loop variables so that they use that dimension.

Comment: As explained: use a few numbers that require two or three digits, and your whole table wont look that nicely aligned.

Comment: @GhostCat True, I've added that requirement to my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to print is a 4-dimensional array, not a 3-dimensional one, as you have 4 layers of grouping. However, here's the modified pretty-print loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < table[i][j].length; k++){
            s += "[";
            for (int l = 0; l < table[i][j][k].length; l++){
                s += table[i][j][k][l];
                if (l != table[i][j][k].length - 1){
                    s += ",";
                }
            }
            s += "]";
            if (k != table[i][j].length - 1){
                s += " ";
            }
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    s += "\n";
}
```

This is the modified value table I'm using:

```
static int[][][][] table = {
        {
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
        },
        {
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
        },
        {
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
                {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
        },
};
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be really close to what I want but it still prints it weirdly, I updated my post with an explanation of why this isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

I made very minor changes to your code. The problem is that k loops over your inner data and you put a newline in several places. I don't think that's what you wanted. You then add more newlines after each loop of k. I removed the extra newlines and then fiddled slightly with making it pretty.

```
public class X {

    int[][][] table = {
        {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}},
        {{101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109}, {111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119}, {121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129}},
        {{201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209}, {211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219}, {221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229}},
    };

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
                s += (j == 0) ? "[" : " [";


                for (int k = 0; k < table[i][j].length; k++) {
                    if (k > 0) {
                        s += ", ";
                    }
                    s += table[i][j][k];
                }
                s += "]";
            }
            s += "\n";
        }

        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X foo = new X();
        System.out.println(foo.toString() );
    }
}

$ javac X.java && java X
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109] [111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119] [121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129]
[201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209] [211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219] [221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229]
```

Comment: You should use a `StringBuilder` for string concatenation.

Comment: I was making minimum changes to the original code. He's a student programmer and didn't need new complexity added.

Comment: @JosephLarson I appreciate the help but to be clear I'm not a student (not anymore), got my degree in December last year. I like to use more simple stuff when it comes to programming as it's easier for me to remember but I do use StringBuilder too sometimes!